# Query database with JPA for null values

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

The value in database can be sometimes `NULL` and sometimes not. How can I retrieve it?
This is my try which makes me suprised:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepo extends JpaRepository<Address, Long>{

    @Query("select count(a) > 0 from Address a where a.street = :street")
    boolean testtest(@Param("street") String street);
}
```

test OK:

```
// given
address = new Address("WIELKA WARSZAAAWA", "Bokserska", "xxx", "50-500");
// when
addressRepo.save(address);
// then
assertTrue(addressRepo.testtest("Bokserska")); // OK
```

test fails:

```
// given
address = new Address("WIELKA WARSZAAAWA", null, "xxx", "50-500");
// when
addressRepo.save(address);
// then
assertTrue(addressRepo.testtest(null)); // cuz false!
```

Comment: You need a query with `where a.street is null`.

Comment: but then normal Queries when `street` is not null won't work!

Comment: You're allowed to use more than a single query. Use the right one depending on what you want to query.

Comment: this will be very uncomfortable to have 12 ifs for this example... `if(street ==null) {addressRepo.testtest2} ... if(city == null) {..} if(street == null && city == null) {...}` etc.

Comment: That's why the criteria API, or QueryDSL, exist: to dynamically create queries.

Answer (score 2):

The JPQL **is not able** to translate this statement:

```
WHERE a.street = null
```

To this SQL:

```
WHERE a.street IS null
```

So, you need to create a new `@Query`:

```
select count(a) > 0 from Address a where a.street IS NULL
```

Mount manually the JPQL string or use Criteria to create a dynamic query are also good options.